# Why is this const only available within the method that calls it?

Tags: javascript

I have this code to create blog posts:

```
let postsArray = []
const titleInput = document.getElementById("post-title")
const bodyInput = document.getElementById("post-body")
const form = document.getElementById("new-post")

function renderPosts() {
    let html = ""
    for (let post of postsArray) {
        html += `
            <h3>${post.title}</h3>
            <p>${post.body}</p>
            <hr />
        `
    }
    document.getElementById("blog-list").innerHTML = html
}

fetch("https://apis.scrimba.com/jsonplaceholder/posts")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        postsArray = data.slice(0, 5)
        renderPosts()
    })

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const postTitle = titleInput.value
    const postBody = bodyInput.value
    const data = {
        title: postTitle,
        body: postBody
    }
    
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
    
    fetch("https://apis.scrimba.com/jsonplaceholder/posts", options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(post => {
            postsArray.unshift(post)
            renderPosts()
            /**
             * Challenge: clear the form out!
             */
            titleInput.value = ""
            bodyInput.value = ""
            // form.reset()
        })
})
```

I tried moving

```
const postTitle = titleInput.value
const postBody = bodyInput.value
```

to the top (outside of the event listener method) and then defining the data variable:

```
 const data = {
        title: postTitle,
        body: postBody
    }
```

However it only works when the postTitle and postBody variables are defined within the event listener method. Why is this? Why are titleInput and bodyInput available when defined outside of the method, but these aren't?

Is it because the .value is only available within the addEventListener method?

Comment: What is the value of an input field before a user has typed anything into it?

Comment: It's empty - so nothing?

Comment: Haha. Ok, I see. Your question answered mine. Thank you.

Comment: You can take a reference to an input field (or other HTML element) when the page loads but you can't get the value associated with that input field until the value has been provided by the user. It's available in the "submit" handler (assuming the user typed in a value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a reference to an input field (or other HTML element) when the page loads, for example:

```
const titleInput = document.getElementById("post-title")
```

But you can't get the value associated with that input field until the value has been provided by the user. It's available at the time the "submit" handler executes (assuming the user typed in a value).

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const postTitle = titleInput.value
    ...
});
```